# how to return the x position of an object without using fixed numbers?

Tags: java

I have a task in currently on, Its a 2D rocket animation, with the rocket composed of 3 separate objects, a nose(triangle), body(square) and a jet(circle).

I have to set the body(s) relative to the nose(t) so that they align when the rocket moves.

this is the rocket class,

```
public Rocket(Triangle t, Square s, Circle c) {
  this.nose = t;
  this.body = s; 
  this.jet = c;    
  this.nose.setXPos(50);//initial positions of the nose X
  this.nose.setYPos(300);//initial positions of the nose Y
  this.body.setXPos(getBodyXPos());//sets the body relative to the nose X
  this.body.setYPos(getBodyYPos());//sets the body relative to the nose Y
```

these are the methods i have to use.

```
private int getBodyXPos() {
 return ;
}

private int getBodyYPos() {
  return ;
}
```

these methods cannot use fixed numbers, rather calculate position of the nose and set the body to this. So, How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you not just subtract half the height of the square from the lower y bound of the triangle?

Comment: If you set `note=t` you should not need to set its X and Y after, when you give the Triangle to the Constructor it should have its X and Y

Comment: If the nose has a constant position, why doesn't the body?  Normally when you move the rocket, you'd move the rocket's position and not each piece individually

Comment: t has already been set in the constructor, (x=50,y=300) the nose, along with the body and jet will move later on in the program as one rocket, i need to set the body to move along with the nose so it looks essentially joined as one object but i am not to use a fixed number.